# How selecting a specific value and joining it to the first result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement that returns me a few column from a table. 
I have a "daySince" column (the 3rd) which is actually a date diff.

I need to select one more column (as numberOfRecord) which would represent the number of row having the same "daySince" value. 
I just appended the number 7 here to explain how the structure would look like, even tho the  correct values for that column would be:

- 1 for rows having daySince val between 10 and 14
- 8 for rows having daySince val 15
- 2 for rows having daySince val 16

Hope that what I'm asking does make sense.
I tried to run some random left, right, and full outer join with awful result. 
Anyone can address me to the right way?

Here's the example query

> ```
> SELECT username, id, DATEDIFF( creation, '2018/02/28') as daySince, 7 as numberOfRecord
> FROM MyTable 
> ORDER BY daySince ASC
> ```

```
username  id daySince numberOfRecord
rob 2D8836  11  7
rob 2D8836  12  7
rob 2D8836  13  7
rob 2D8836  14  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  15  7
rob 2D8836  16  7
rob 2D8836  16  7
```

Comment: Please include your current query.  Also, your sample data appears to be cut off and is difficult to read.

Comment: To add to @TimBiegeleisen 's comment also provide data as formatted text not as a image.. And a formatted text output from with the resuls you expect.

Comment: It won't make difference since I asked to consider that select as a table, but as you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This.

```
        SELECT
            username, id, 
            DATEDIFF( creation, '2018/02/28') as daySince, 
            Count(DATEDIFF( creation, '2018/02/28')) as numberOfRecord
        FROM MyTable 
        Group By DATEDIFF( creation, '2018/02/28')
        ORDER BY daySince ASC
```

Comment: thanks, it was easier than i though... I've so much to learn -,-
One more thing, my post title wasn't very clear, how would you rename it ?

Comment: @Koop4 Most welcome. I know the title is not clear. but the problem of one developer easily understands by another developer.

Comment: Your inclusion of `username` and `id` in the `SELECT` is just bad SQL and would be (properly) rejected in the more recent versions of MySQL.

Comment: they are fake column name used as example since i've been asked to write the sql statement and provide data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want, you should either be aggregating by `username, id`:

```
SELECT username, id, DATEDIFF(creation, '2018-02-28') as daySince, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY username, id, DATEDIFF( creation, '2018-02-28')
ORDER BY daySince ASC;
```

Or you should remove `username` and `id`, because they are irrelevant:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(creation, '2018-02-28') as daySince, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY DATEDIFF( creation, '2018-02-28')
ORDER BY daySince ASC;
```

Comment: I actually need those column.

Comment: @Koop4 . . . Then use the first version.  If you need them, they should be in the `group by`.